# Weirdity with Google search result time stamp

Tags: discussion, google

Even though this is likely nothing to do with Stack Overflow and completely unimportant, I just noticed something weird.

This question was asked 10 minutes ago

[Request.Files Comes Empty on Occasion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234987/request-files-comes-empty-on-occasion#60234987)

[image]

However Google says it was asked 7 hours ago

[image]

I'm not *saying* it’s aliens... But *it’s* aliens

<sub>*Badly hewn (child like) red circles for your enjoyment*</sub>

Comment: The time is [correct for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6boF7.png). Strange

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe you have the time travel option switched off? Check your settings.

Comment: @CertainPerformance try this search string ["*Request.Files sometimes null*"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQYPg9g9z2nqiDJt06YiuV2diQ70Q%3A1581728581009&source=hp&ei=RENHXvzHO-Oa4-EP2Y6GoAo&q=Request.Files+sometimes+null&oq=Request.Files+sometimes+null&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2057.2057..2495...0.0..0.179.179.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.bJc8C7HHkvo&ved=0ahUKEwj8-cyRrtLnAhVjzTgGHVmHAaQQ4dUDCAg&uact=5)

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it from that link, currently says 6 hours ago. Maybe Google is using different logic for the top result of a site vs the other results for a site. None of the timestamps in SO's HTML look off, so it sounds like a Google thing

Comment: Could this be a time zone issue? Either between you and Google's servers or between Google's servers and SO's servers.

Comment: Nothing unusual about an SO user deleting their question and asking it again, happens all the time.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, i hadn't thought of that possibility. Though in this scheme of things, even if this was a bug, i think there are bigger problems in the world